# Oracle sum most recent records until a defined value then Ignore the rest

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions, cumulative-sum

Im looking to sum a column until a defined value then ignore the rest of the records.

| ID | WHEN | VALUE | AVG_COL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 2016 | 6 | 84.5 |
| 101 | 2015 | 3 | 76 |
| 101 | 2014 | 3 | 87 |
| 101 | 2013 | 15 | 85.8 |
| 101 | 2012 | 6 | 92 |
| 101 | 2011 | 3 | 81 |
| 101 | 2010 | 3 | 82.3 |

I need a single result set of

| ID | VALUE | AVG_COL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 30 | 82.3 |

I have tried the following

```
SELECT
   ID,
   WHEN,
   VALUE,
   AVG_COL,
   SUM(VALUE) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY WHEN) AS VALUE, --must equal 30
   AVG(AVG_COL) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AVG
FROM
    TABLE_ONE
WHERE
   VALUE = 30;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. How did you get AVG_COL equals to 82,3?

Comment: @ekochergin Sorry! 85.06!

Comment: you have to use window functions

Comment: maybe it's as simple as `least(sum(value) over (partition by id order by when), 30)`?

Comment: Please describe in what order you want to perform summation and what is the rule to calculate the result of `avg_col`. It's totally unclear how did you get 82.3 (or 85.06 for which you need to edit the question and update the desired result with correct value)

Answer (score 0):

Hi try some thing like this, where modified the WHERE clause

-- Untested

```
SELECT
   ID,
   WHEN,
   VALUE,
   AVG_COL,
   SUM(VALUE) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY WHEN) AS VALUE, --must equal 30
   AVG(AVG_COL) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AVG
FROM
    TABLE_ONE
WHERE
   ID IN (SELECT ID FROM ( (SELECT ID, sum(VALUE) sum_val FROM 
           TABLE_ONE GROUP BY ID) WHERE SUM_VAL = 30);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select id,
SUM(VALUE) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY WHEN RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS VALUE,
AVG(AVG_COL) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AVG
from table_one
where VALUE <= 30
order by when desc
fetch first 1 rows only;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the running sum with window functions, then filter and limit in an outer query.

Assuming a table like `(id, dt, val, . . .)`:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*,
        sum(val) over(partition by id order by dt) sum_val
    from mytable t
) t
where sum_val >= 30
order by row_number() over(partition by id order by dt desc)
fetch first row with ties
```

Notes:

- this handles multiple ids at once
- for each id, this brings the first row where the running sum of the value reaches at least 30, if any (rows are processed by descending date)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is running sum of values and a decision on what order by you want to apply for that running sum.
SAMPLE DATA

```sql
WITH
    tbl AS
        (
            Select 101 "ID", 2016 "YR",  6 "VAL", 84.5 "AVG_COL" From Dual Union All
            Select 101 "ID", 2015 "YR",  3 "VAL",   76 "AVG_COL" From Dual Union All
            Select 101 "ID", 2014 "YR",  3 "VAL",   87 "AVG_COL" From Dual Union All
            Select 101 "ID", 2013 "YR", 15 "VAL", 85.8 "AVG_COL" From Dual Union All
            Select 101 "ID", 2012 "YR",  6 "VAL",   92 "AVG_COL" From Dual Union All
            Select 101 "ID", 2011 "YR",  3 "VAL",   81 "AVG_COL" From Dual Union All
            Select 101 "ID", 2010 "YR",  3 "VAL", 82.3 "AVG_COL" From Dual 
        ),
```

Create CTE (I named it grid) to prepare your data - in this case I used descending order by years:

```sql
  grid AS
    (
        Select
          ID, YR, 
          VAL, 
          Sum(VAL) OVER(Partition By ID Order By YR DESC Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) "RUNNING_SUM",
          CASE WHEN Sum(VAL) OVER(Partition By ID Order By YR DESC Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) >= 30
               THEN Sum(1) OVER(Partition By ID Order By YR DESC Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row)  
          END "IS_OVER_RN",
          AVG_COL,
          Round(AVG(AVG_COL) OVER(Partition By ID Order By YR DESC Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row), 2) "RUNNING_AVG"
        From
          tbl
    )
```

This cte is resulting as:

```sql
        ID         YR        VAL RUNNING_SUM IS_OVER_RN    AVG_COL RUNNING_AVG
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------- ---------- ---------- -----------
       101       2016          6           6                  84.5        84.5 
       101       2015          3           9                    76       80.25 
       101       2014          3          12                    87        82.5 
       101       2013         15          27                  85.8       83.33 
       101       2012          6          33          5         92       85.06 
       101       2011          3          36          6         81       84.38 
       101       2010          3          39          7       82.3       84.09
```

Now you can get your result with the code below

```sql
-- Main SQL 
SELECT
    ID, RUNNING_SUM, RUNNING_AVG
FROM
    grid g
WHERE IS_OVER_RN = (Select Min(IS_OVER_RN) From grid Where ID = g.ID)
```

Result:

```sql
-- with YEARS in DESCENDING order
        ID RUNNING_SUM RUNNING_AVG
---------- ----------- -----------
       101          33       85.06
```

If you make orderings within analytic functions in grid cte ASCENDING then the same main SQL would result with:

```sql
-- with YEARS in ASCENDING order
        ID RUNNING_SUM RUNNING_AVG
---------- ----------- -----------
       101          30        82.5
```